# Can a method that supposed to return value be used like method that returns nothing (void)?

Tags: java, android, methods, return, void

I came across this code:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

and the method registerListener() returnes a boolean value ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,android.hardware.Sensor,int,android.os.Handler) , though this code uses it like it returnes nothing.

How is that possible?

Comment: There is nothing illegal in such kind of invocation and return type can remain unused.

Comment: [You can view the source here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java) Also, what user1873880 said. The return type doesn't have to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the value returned by `registerListener()`.

Consider this code:

```
void performOperation() {
    doSomething(); 
}
```

`doSomething` does something and returns `true` if the operation was successfully done, `false` otherwise.

`performOperation`   doesn't `return` a thing, it simply performs the operation.

Another example:

[public boolean delete()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29):

> Returns:
>        true if and only if the file or directory is successfully deleted; false otherwise

You don't have to use the value returned by `delete` method (but it's highly recommended to).

---

**Clarification**:

You're probably confused with [method signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) in this situation.

Methods are declared like:

`modifier return-type name(parameters ..)`

When your method declared to return something, it **must** return something! But if you use it within another method that returns nothing (void), then you're not forced to use this value.

Comment: But don't am I supposed to set the returned value from doSomething() to something? like a boolean variable or if statement? I am sorry, i just don't get it because I learned that a method that returnes a value (doSomething() in your case) should be assign to variable or something that will take that value...

Comment: @user1919052   yes assign that statement to a boolean then  after executing that method your boolean variable value will be *true if the sensor is supported and successfully enabled.*

Comment: @user1919052: Only if you need to use that value for something. It's perfectly fine (and very common) not to use the return value of a function. There are times, of course, when it's essential to use the return value, depending on the function, but other times when the return value is more just extra information you may not need to use. (In this case, I'd tend to think it would be useful to know if the sensor was present and enabled, but perhaps code earlier on had already determined that.)

Comment: Oh, now after the edit I understood. Thanks a loot you really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Java does not force you to assign the values of expressions to variables, including method calls. There are quite a few examples of this in the standard library - for example, [`Map.put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) returns the previous value associated with a key, which can be useful but is often ignored.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("a", "1"); // Ignoring the returned value
String previousValue = map.put("a", "2"); // Assigning the returned value ("1") to a new variable
```

Related aside: you can even ignore new instances of objects returned by `new` (but there is probably no good use case for doing this):

```
new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, every expression can be made into a statement by adding a semicolon. The value computed by the expression is ignored.

This isn't restricted to method call expressions; the following is also valid.

```
int a=2;
a + 40;  // compute 42, don't store
```

You probably do this more than you think. Assignment to a variable is also an expression, the value of which is usually thrown away. Very rarely you see code like this:

```
int b = (a = 56); // store result of assignment
```